# Media query css always display horizontal scrollbar

Tags: iphone

My site is:  alwaysriding.co.uk

I had updated and use media query to make it displays better on smartphone but I am having some problem with `zoom in`, `zoom out`.

When you go to my site with smartphone, you will see the horizontal scrollbar althought I had fixed the `width = 480px`.

You can see my css if you resize your browser windows.

Thanks in advance.

Chu